# Write permission error in /tmp in python call to MySQL on Centos 7

Tags: mysql, php, permissions, centos7, python

I have a python (3.6 anaconda distribution) scrip on **Centos 7** which at some point executes a simple query of the following structure

```
import MySQLdb

cursor = cnn.cursor()  # cnn is the open connection to MySQL db
cursor.execute(strSQL) # cursor is the active cursor of cnn, 
                       # and strSQL is a simple SELECT query
```

The python script is being called from PhP (via *exec*) for data processing.

The cursor **execute** statement above throws the following error

```
Can't create/write to file '/tmp/MYC8vAAs' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)
```

All these programs work with no problems when called from the terminal window or locally on Ubuntu (VM on widows). I have very little expertise of system administration, but from what I've googled so far, all arrows are pointing to correct permission of **/tmp** folder (like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/84890/cant-create-write-to-file-tmp-sql-xxxx-myi-errcode-13) for example), but in my case the permissions are as follows

```
drwxrwxrwx.
```

and I cannot think of any reason as why this is happening.
Your insights on this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The permissions on your `/tmp` folder are wrong.  `chmod 1777 /tmp` should fix that.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried that, the permission became **drwxrwxrwt**, but nothing changed, still get the very same error.

Comment: @Hayk You should restart MySQL. And you should probably try to figure out _how_ `/tmp` got its wrong permissions.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, thanks for the comment. I tried to restart MySQL with systemctl restart mysqld but it did not work and now MySQL is down. What I see from the MySQL logs is the following mysqld: 
      *Can't create/write to file '/tmp/iblbBbVr' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)*

tmp has all permissions, but MySQL fails to write on it. What can I do now?

Comment: @Hayk How did `/tmp` get wrong permissions to begin with?

Comment: well, I don't remember that I changed it by hand. All was working fine until recently, and I still cannot restart MySQL. /tmp now has the correct permissions following the comments above,  but then how can it be that MySQL still cannot write there ? Is there anything else I'm overlooking ?

Comment: assuming `/tmp` permissions are set to correct `chmod 1777 /tmp` bit, you may want to check your file system (`touch /forcefsck ; systemctl -i reboot`)

Comment: Also make sure that the disk isn't full.